# How to modify dynamic string contents in C#

Tags: c#, string

I'm new in programming. I just need someone who can tell me how to replace string values in C#? The values which I'm referring to are dynamic which means I cannot use .Replace .

Comment: Some sample data with desired output pls..

Comment: You'll need to provide more context than that to get an answer. Can you post some code perhaps?

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "C sharp". The language is named "C#".

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use Replace

```
String toBeReplaced = "can't";
String toBeReplacedWith = "can";
String sentence="I can't use Replace";
sentence = sentence.Replace(toBeReplaced,toBeReplacedWith);
```

sentence becomes "I can use Replace"

Comment: @Cybernate I don't think OP fully understands how Replace works and thinks that he can only use constant strings as arguments

Comment: OP is likely mistaken- he also says that he is new to programming.

Comment: @Matt: Could be true.. however unless we see some sample data and output I can't be so sure..

Comment: I edited the answer to better show how string variables can be used

Comment: @All....what I'm trying to create is a CSS editor. Upon loading the editor, user can see the existing CSS file in a textbox and user has the option to change the font-family, size, color and etc. The value of those attributes(font-family, size, color) is what I'm referring to "dynamic" values which I want to modify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it depends on what object you are going to hold in this `dynamic` field, then you can make a decision to chose the correct way :

```
        dynamic tempDynamic = "hello";
        Type objectType = tempDynamic.GetType();

        if (objectType == typeof(String))
        {
            string tempStr = tempDynamic.ToString();
            tempStr = tempStr.Replace("hello", "goodbye");
            tempDynamic = tempStr;

            // at this time do what ever you like with your dynamic
        }
        else
        {
            // Go with another ...
        }
```

In this way You have to ensure of what types your `dynamic` is going to hold. 
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what types your `dynamic` is going to hold, try this:

```
//lets assume that `dynamicStuff.whatever` is a string//

dynamic dynamicStuff;
string dynStr = dynamicStuff.whatever;
dynStr = dynStr.Replace("Your replace string");
```